# How can I capture the string "word1/word2/*" with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need to build a regular expression that accepts the following pattern:

```
word1/word2/*
word1/*
```

`word2` is optional, and it needs to end with `/*`.

I tried this regexp:

```
(word1)/(word2)?/\*
```

It matches this input: `word1/word2/*`

but not this: `word1/*`

Comment: Do you need to capture the values of `word1` and `word2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **move the first `/` into the following capture group** (parenthesized subexpression):

```
(word1)(/word2)?/\*
```

If you want to capture `word2` *without the leading `/`*, introduce an *additional* capture group:

```
(word1)(/(word2))?/\*
```

**Note**:

- Depending on your specific environment, you may be able to avoid unneeded capture groups via non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`).

Comment: Note: This answer is - indirectly - discussed on [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426495/45375)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
word1(?:/word2)?/\*
```

The `(?: )` construct is a non-capturing group. The `?` after it means "zero or one of the previous atom." So this matches `word1` optionally followed by `/word2`, then a final slash and asterisk.

(I'm assuming that's a literal asterisk that you want to match, not a wildcard asterisk as in "any characters"; if it's the latter you want, replace `\*` with `.*`.)

(You can put the capturing groups `()` back in on `word1` and `word2` if you need them.)

Comment: This won't capture the values of `word1` and `word2`, which it seems OP wants to do based on the current regex, but hopefully they'll confirm whether this is the case.

Comment: @Michelle Added a note to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer, I believe its more lean.

```
(((word)(1|2)/){1,2}\*)
```

Much less code, try it out.

Comment: I think it is fair to assume that `word1` and `word2` in the question are merely _placeholders_, so they shouldn't be assumed to share a common prefix / fixed suffixes.